# How to get a Youtube channel RSS feed after 2015 April 20 (without v3 API)?

Tags: php, youtube, rss

Now that API v2 is gone, what would be a way to get a simple RSS feed of a channel, without v3 API? I'm open to Yahoo Pipes or any workaround that is simpler than creating an application for v3 API if the target is a feed reader. I only need an RSS feed. It was available publicly until now and it can cease any minute now (I think). So why not let access to it without an API key anymore.

Comment: I used to use an RSS feed for a keyword search result like this: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q=painting+miniatures+tutorial&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-search&v=2 those RSS feeds maybe gone for good. I need more time to come to grips with v3.

Comment: OP should accept AitorF's answer instead of Dan's because it's better (and the votes speak for themselves).

Comment: OK. But for me personally the scraping method is more universal and works better.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

At *RSS Reader* section https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6098135?hl=en there is an option to export to an OPML file your subscriptions. Then, looking at the contents of the OPML you can extract the feeds, and the structure of each feed is:

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=XXXX
```

So you could generate new feeds from this structure if you know the channel id. This kind of feeds are not getting the "https://youtube.com/devicesupport" error, so I expect they are going to keep working.

Comment: You can get the channel id by searching for the attribute `data-channel-external-id` in the source code of the youtube page

Comment: Good to know this but unfortunately that feed doesn't contain video thumbnails or any info about the videos. Forgot to mention those were needed.

Comment: @Firsh The images are in the format  
`http://i.ytimg.com/vi/[videoid]/default.jpg` (square) and  `http://i.ytimg.com/vi/[videoid]/hqdefault.jpg` (high quality).

Comment: You can also use the youtube username instead of the channel id as follows:

    https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=xxxxxx

Comment: @JohnChandler the user=xxxx is something official that is going to keep working?

Comment: That feed doesn't appear to validate: https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Ffeeds%2Fvideos.xml%3Fchannel_id%3DUCVUx0VcNxnHx7ZjuZK5Sthw

Comment: This only returns 15 results, my client has 130 videos and growing.  Any way to page through these?

Comment: Don't think so. You are not likely to get the videos from 16 to 130+, but you will be updated with the videos your client uploads from now on.

Answer (score 67):

You can get the feeds like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=CHANNELID
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=USERNAME
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=YOUR_YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_NUMBER
```

But the JSON format which used to be supported (with additional parameter `&alt=JSON`) is not supported anymore.

Additionally you can request for API key for public access to your YouTube videos from your [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and get YouTube Videos, Playlists in JSON format like this:

```
- Get Channels: 
  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&forUsername={YOUR_USER_NAME}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
- Get Playlists: 
  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&channelId={YOUR_CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
- Get Playlist Videos: 
  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus&playlistId={YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

More information from [YouTube v3 docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos).

Comment: Can you get RSS feeds for search results, that used to be support in v2.

Comment: do you know how to break the limit from youtube playlist? This returns only 5 results even when the playlist have to much more videos

Answer (score 10):

in you tube, click on the subscriptions on the left hand pane. This will open up all your subscriptions in the center of the page. Scroll down and you'll find a Export to RSS reader button which produces an xml file of all your subscriptions . I've done this and added it to my prefered rss reader feedly.

Comment: This is definitely the best solution. I don't understand why Google doesn't put these links front and centre.

To get the feed without subscribing, see source of channel page, and find this line:
`<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=_channel ID_">`

Answer (score 6):

If you inspect any Youtube channel page, inside the `<head>` you will find an rss meta node like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" 
      type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS"     
      href="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCn8zNIfYAQNdrFRrr8oibKw">
```

This should provide you with the data you need.

Comment: this may have changed to no longer be true in early 2017

Answer (score 6):

Get the channel id by searching for the attribute data-channel-external-id in the source code of the YouTube channel page. (thanks to helq).

This code will grab all video titles and ids from the feed and dump it into an array:

```
$channel_id = 'XXX'; // put the channel id here
$youtube = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id='.$channel_id);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($youtube, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$youtube = json_decode($json, true);
$yt_vids = array();
$count = 0;
foreach ($youtube['entry'] as $k => $v) {
    $yt_vids[$count]['id'] = str_replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '', $v['link']['@attributes']['href']);
    $yt_vids[$count]['title'] = $v['title'];
    $count++;
}
print_r($yt_vids);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've created a small PHP script that scrapes a Youtube URL for video links, and then outputs them as an atom feed: https://gist.github.com/Skalman/801436d9693ff03bc4ce

URLs such as https://www.youtube.com/user/scishow/videos work.

Caveats:

- The tool doesn't scrape dates
- Playlists won't include more than 100 videos
- Playlists include the "play all" link
- Author is correctly set only for channels (e.g. not playlists)
- Maybe Youtube will block you if you use this too much (but hopefully the limits are high enough)
- Likely several more...

Comment: You pointed me into the right direction, I took it to the next level and tailored the script according to my specific needs. I managed to scrape dates where available (in the nice format), thumbnails etc. I don't believe YT would block, as the user agent is set as a browser and it won't scrape very often anyway. The only problem is that the layout might change on YT.

Comment: @Firsh, could you post the modified script? thank you.

Comment: Not sure how usable it will be for you. I no longer needed the RSS format, just the fact that I could scrape. http://snipplr.com/view/98436/improved-youtube-scrapers/ It's part of a much larger WP plugin I make. Sorry if it seems random :) Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

There also exist RSS-Bridge witch can extract RSS feeds from a lot of services like Twitter, Google+, Flickr, Youtube, Identi.ca, etc.

source: https://github.com/sebsauvage/rss-bridge

demo server: https://bridge.suumitsu.eu/

Answer (score 2):

try using this URL:
      https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=USERNAME

Works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

From My Blog Post: `http://tcodesblog.blogspot.com/search/label/howtofindyouryoutubechannelfeed`

---

## HOW TO FIND YOUR YOUTUBE CHANNEL FEED


In the old days, it was easy (2009) but now a days it is much harder to find it (2012-present). Here is a quick way to find your new feed from your YouTube Channel. Remember to follow the list correctly!

1. First find your **channel id**: You can do this by going to your YouTube Channel in the Dashboard
2. Copy the **channel id**: Your **channel id** can be found when visiting your YouTube Channel from within the Dashboard
3. Copy your **channel id**: Copy your **channel id** and replace **channelidgoeshere** below with your **channel id**: `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=channelidgoeshere`
4. Copy your entire YouTube Channel Feed and create a simplified feed: You can do this by creating a shorter feed link in FeedBurner at `http://www.feedburner.com/` (Requires a Google account. Free to use.), which is also part of Google. Create a new feed (select **I'm A Podcaster!** to see your videos appear in the feed and to make your feed compatible with other feed readers such as: Digg Reader, Apple iPhone Apple News App, Apple iPhone Podcasts App, Feedly, etc.) -OR- edit an existing one by copying your entire YouTube Channel Feed and then click **Save Feed Details** as normal
5. Your YouTube Channel Feed now works and your videos can be seen in a feed file directly on your FeedBurner feed. Mine is at YouTube as a feed at `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCvFR6YxwnYfLt_QqRFk_r3g` & at FeedBurner as `http://feeds.feedburner.com/youtube/warrenwoodhouse` with my videos that appear only as text format, as an example, since I need to update mine to show my videos. You can change different settings in FeedBurner and do other things so it's worth a try since it's free and easy to use. I highly recommend using FeedBurner or another feed creation service, however, FeedBurner is your best bet since it also includes cross-feed subscription service mechanism (USM - Universal Subscription Mechanism), which means your feed can be read from any compatible device such as a computer, mobile phone (with the correct app installed), via an older web browser (such as Internet Explorer which supports Web Slices & RSS/Atom/XML Feeds).

Your feed can also be opened up in Apple iPhone Apple News App & Apple iPhone Podcasts App on your Apple iPhone, Apple iPod Touch and Apple iPad if you've set the settings correctly to USM (Universal Subscription Mechanism). Once this is in effect, your feed can be viewed through different services and devices.

Your feed on FeedBurner allows you to create an Email Subscription, Headline Animator (which shows you how a link to the latest post) along with how many subscribers, Chiclets and other cool stuff.

I hope this answer proves useful and if you want to see some more cool awesome coding practices by me, please feel free to check out my T-Codes website at `http://warrenwoodhouse.webs.com/codes` for lots more stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an example Yahoo Pipes here.
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=6eeff0110a81f2ab94e8472620770b11

You can run this pipe by pressing "Run Pipe" without API Key filled. But you must provide your own API Key and channel id (which can be obtained via channels API) when cloned. Wanted to automate fetching channelId by YouTube username but not easy to pipe.

Comment: Pipes is discontinued on 30 Sept 2015 :(

Comment: Yes, that is a bummer. I will write an Apps Script which does similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a batch script that creates an RSS feed of your new subscription videos. You don't need an API key. The script uses 2 external tools: YouTube-DL and Xidel.

Anyway, read the following thread, and go to post 98 to download the script:
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3946#c98

I hope someone codes this to php, python, javascript, powershell or bash.

Comment: I wasn't aware youtube-dl had that function - thanks. It seems to be fairly well hidden in the docs too...

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some changes in youtube response so i make some changes to get channel id from rss feed using Curl.

```
$channel_id = 'XXXXXXXX'; // put the channel id here

//using curl
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id='.$channel_id.'&orderby=published';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
$response  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response=simplexml_load_string($response);
$json = json_encode($response);
$youtube= json_decode($json, true);

$count = 0;
if(isset($youtube['entry']['0']) && $youtube['entry']['0']!=array())
{
    foreach ($youtube['entry'] as $k => $v) {
        $yt_vids[$count]['id'] = str_replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '', $v['link']['@attributes']['href']);
        $yt_vids[$count]['title'] = $v['title'];
        $count++;
    }
}
else
{
    $yt_vids[$count]['id']=str_replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '', $youtube['entry']['link']['@attributes']['href']);
    $yt_vids[$count]['title']=$youtube['title'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($yt_vids);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code to integrate Youtube Feed with [wordpress custom field "ACF plugin"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) & [FancyBox](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/)

```
    <?php  
    $channel_id = get_field('youtube_chanel_id'); //ACF text field
    if ($channel_id){ // if channel_id not empty -- START
    $youtube = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id='.$channel_id);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($youtube, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $youtube = json_decode($json, true);
        echo'<div class="col-md-12 youtube-videos-feed">';  
        foreach ($youtube['entry'] as $k => $v) {
            $id = str_replace(array("yt:video:"), "", $v['id']); // Remove "yt:video:" from ID value
            //$date = $v['updated']; // video updated date (disabled for now)
            $title = $v['title']; // video title
            echo '<a class="with-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=',$id,'&autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=0" data-fancybox="videos"  data-caption="',$title,'" title="',$title,'" >
                <div class="col-md-3 main-image post-image img-fancy">
                    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/',$id,'/0.jpg" alt="',$title,'" >
                </div>
            </a>';
        }
        echo'</div>';
    } // if channel_id not empty -- END
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a Chrome extension named [Youtube RSS-ify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-rss-ify/fogofhbdjhkglfhbaeckigmhponmaifi) that injects an RSS icon on video, channel and navigation pages.  It was just what I was looking for.

[image: Youtube RSS-ify extension screenshot]

Icons look like this:

[image: Youtube RSS-ify RSS icon]

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using an excellent rss parser. Many of them are available, but you can try http://simplepie.org/, one of the best I used for my personal projects.

Its pretty well documented with some examples.

**Usage example**

Note:Used YouTube channel college humor, you can get it from the channel page itself

```
<?php
include_once('../autoloader.php');
// Parse it
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCPDXXXJj9nax0fr0Wfc048g');
$feed->enable_cache(false);
$feed->init();

$items = $feed->get_items();

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    echo $item->get_title() . "\n";
}

var_dump($feed->get_item_quantity());
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to get the channel id:

Open Subscription Manager (left panel, down below subscriptions) and click on the desired user.

The url will be in the form: 
`https://www.youtube.com/channel/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

So the feed url should be:

`https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

*Note:* Better use channel ids rather than user names because user names may change.