# Unusual traffic (403) error when using youtube rss api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For the last 48h I'm getting 403 error when trying to get rss feeds using `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=...` with the message:

> ```
> We're sorry... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.
> ```

I'm running small crawler on my hosting for checking newest videos on few channels. It's been working OK for more than 2 years, until last Sunday. I've talked about this issue with my hosting provider, but they haven't changed anything in network configuration etc.

What can I do about this? How long I have to wait to be able to use rss api again? Is there any limit of queries I can send to youtube per day?
Is it possible to add my hosting server's ip to whitelist or something?

I totally don't understand this - it's rss api and it is meant for use by other programs to send automated queries...

Answer (score 0):

I try it myself and it is working for me. I suggest you to check it again if it is now working or use the channel_id instead of user.

So your request should look like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=YOUR_CHANNEL_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

## For your question How long I have to wait to be able to use rss api again? Is there any limit of queries I can send to youtube per day?

Remember that the YouTube DATA API has a courtesy limit/quota of

```
Queries per day                     1,000,000   
Queries per 100 seconds per user    300,000 
Queries per 100 seconds             3,000,000
```

These quotas are reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT).

For more information, check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752447/how-to-get-a-youtube-channel-rss-feed-after-2015-april-20-without-v3-api).

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue.

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=YOUR_CHANNEL_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Using this url with my API key in my browser works but I still end up with a 403 on my server.

I'm doing other call on https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos with the same API key, and these work fine.

I'm using Tiny RSS. It look like Feedly is also having troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is working fine for me again for the last 4 days.